# Firefox bar to quickly find API docs

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

This question is related to this one
[Tricks to Google for desired page quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573072/tricks-to-google-for-desired-page-quickly)

Firefox can do some magic and bring exactly the required pages. E.g.

```
  java 6 SimpleDateFormat
  ruby doc rexml
```

But some times it fails giving a usual google results:

```
  ruby rexml
```

And some times I whould like it to go to different a location:

```
javascript array slice

  I see
    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp
  but whould like it to be
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
```

How it works, btw? Where can I find all existing mappings, and how can I add/edit them? If they can be viewed/edited as text document, it whould be cool.

Answer (score 3):

You can add [YubNub](http://yubnub.org) as a search engine, (It's my default) and then your api docs of choice as a YubNub command if it doesn't exist already.  I use it for Ruby all the time, e.g. `rdoc String`

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Use the right-hand side search box where a search provider is available. MDC once had such a provider, but their search engine sucks big times. For example SO has such a provider. It's denoted by a shade of blue on the arrow right there.
2. Navigate to a particular search engine, right click the search field and "Add a Keyword for this Search". You may add "js" for example. In the future all you have to do is to type "js array slice" in the address bar and FF will bring you to the search results page of that particular search engine.
3. If there's no search engine on that site, use [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/), define engines as you like and then follow steps at point 2.

If you want to modify the built-in search engine for address bar, open a new tab, go to about:config and then search for "keyword.URL".

Answer (score 0):

These aren't mappings, it's a Google Lucky search, isn't it?

Comment: May be, as Fx gives same results as Google Lucky... But Google always display first matched page, while Firefox can decide to display full search results, e.g. for 'ruby rexml'. 

May be it some how related to http://www.wormus.com/leakytap/Internet/CustomKeywords ?

Comment: Hmm.. 'ruby rexml' redirects me directly to http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml. Perhaps it's in the Firefox options